# Auto upgrade of wpf application with InstallShield LE?

Tags: wpf, installshield-le

I have a WPF application. I am creating setup using InstallShield 2013 LE. I want click once like auto update functionality for my application.

Is there any auto update functionality provided with InstallShield 2013 LE like Click once ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just update your current version number.

InstallshieldProject -> 1 Organize your Setup -> General Information

Change:

- Product Version
- Product Code

DONOT CHANGE

- Upgrade Code

Then

InstallshieldProject -> 1 Organize your Setup -> Upgrade Paths

add at least one Item:

Set Values:
 - minversion 0.0.0
 - maxversion currentversion
 - Upgrade Code (from General Information)

```
//Now you can install the new version over the old Version
```

Comment: I don't want to install a setup again . I want something like google chrome auto update functionality ( download and update new version automatically just need to restart it).

Comment: You can call your Setup via Process.Start("xxx.exe"); before that you should download the current version from your server to the filesystem.. eg. to AppData/V1.2/setup.exe. But you will have to think about an update strategy, like parsing an xml-File with infos from the current version, then you should check your Version, if server version is newer, download the file, start the setup, close current instance of your programm

Comment: So I have to write my own logic to do this.. there is noting with install shield LE ?

Comment: I don`t now any other way.